# get specific records based on where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with country, state, city and locality. I want to get only those countries which are having either city or locality as null or empty. I tried this query:

```
select distinct country from xyz where state != "" and ((city="" and Locality="") or (city="" and Locality!="") or (city!="" and Locality="")) order by country
```

Basically need to fetch all the countries where either city or locality value is empty. This query gives me few countries which are having city and locality both in same row. What am I doing wrong? Its giving me countries which are having city and Locality both values.

I need country list which doesn't have city or Locality which means all the cities or locality of the country is empty or null. Do not want country if even one record of the country has either city or locality value.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a simple `or`:

```
select distinct country
from xyz
where state <> '' and
      (city = '' or Locality= '')
order by country;
```

If this doesn't return what you want, you might have a problem with `NULL` values:

```
select distinct country
from xyz
where state <> '' and
      (city = '' or Locality= '' or city is null or Locality is null)
order by country;
```

Or possibly the condition on `state` is not needed.

By the way, you should use single quotes rather than double quotes for string constants in SQL.

EDIT:

If you want a query where *all* the values are empty or `NULL` for a given country, then use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select country
from xyz
group by contry
having min(city = '' or Locality= '' or city is null or Locality is null) > 0
order by country;
```

Comment: This gives me all the countries where even single record has city or locality empty out of all the records. In this case sum will be always greater than 0.

Comment: The edit to your question explicitly asks for this:  "I need country list which doesn't have city or Locality which means all the cities or locality of the country is empty or null. Do not want country if even one record of the country has either city or locality value.".

Comment: Let's say for country 'abc' I have 4 city records. Out of them 2 records are empty and 2 are having city values. In this case, sum(city='') will be greater than 0. I just want country which has all citi as empty. same applies to locality.

Comment: @CM. . . . Duh.  That should have been `min()`.

Comment: Awesome :) I was doing sum(city = '') = count(city). min() is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct country
from xyz
where state != ""
and (city="" or Locality="")
```

Answer (score 0):

need to use `or` instead of `and`

```
select distinct country from xyz where state <> "" and (city="" or city is null or Locality="" or Locality is null) order by country
```

Comment: @CM By updating your question this SO post is now no a valid question/answer structure. I have voted to close.

Comment: @JanDoggen - In that case, should I add one more question?

Comment: I think I judged to fast; looking at the edit queue I see that you did not edit your original query, only the text. Retracted the close vote.

Comment: @CM you really need to learn how to use and/or in your question. I guess you meant `which means all the cities AND locality of the country is empty or null`

Comment: It should be 'all the cities OR all the locality of the country is empty or null'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct country from xyz where (state != "" and (city="" OR Locality=""))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IsNull` property.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM xyz
WHERE state <> '' AND
  (city = '' OR Locality= '' OR city IS NULL OR Locality IS NULL)
ORDER BY country;
```

An `int` value can never contain the value `''`. If you have any `int` value in `city` or `Locality`